# prime ideal in a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A$ be a ring, $B$ a subring of $A$ and $p$ a prime ideal of $A$. Let $f: B \rightarrow A$ the natural homomorphism. Then, $B/f^{-1}(p)$ is a subring of $A/p$.

I'm trying to prove the above, and I don't really think I understand the question. Does $B/f^{-1}(p)$ is a subring of $A/p$ mean that $B/f^{-1}(p)$ is literally a subring of $A/p$? Or is it $B/f^{-1}(p)$ is isomorphic to one of the subrings of $A/p$?

Answer (score 1):

The below is a bit formal, but it encodes the idea that the function $f$ which makes $B$ a subring of $A$ can be used to "naturally" make $B/f^{-1}(p)$ a subring of $A/p$.

It means the following:  First, that $B/f^{-1}(p)$ is a ring.

Then, define a map $\bar{f}:B/f^{-1}(p)\to A/p$ as follows.  For $\bar{b}\in B/f^{-1}(p)$, let $b\in B$ be any element that maps to $\bar{b}$ under the projection $\pi _B:B\to B/f^{-1}(p)$.  let $\bar{f}(\bar{b})=\pi _A(f(b))$ where $\pi _A:A\to A/p$ is the projection.  Show that $\bar{f}$ is an injective ring homorphism ( ie. that $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism of $B/f^{-1}(p)$ onto a subring of $A/p$ ).

Comment: So is $\pi_A \circ f \circ \pi_B^{-1}$ an isomorphism from $B/f^{-1}(p)$ to a subring of $A/p$? Is this mapping well-defined?

Comment: Yes, I would say that's part of the question that was asked.  Basically you have to check that if $\pi_B (b_1)=\pi_B (b_2)$, then $\pi_A(f(b_1))=\pi_A(f(b_2))$, that is, if $b_1$ and $b_2$ differ by an element of $f^{-1}(p)$, then $f(b_1)$ and $f(b_2)$ differ by an element of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not literally a subring because it is not even a subset of $A/P$.

But you can show it is isomorphic to $\pi(Im(f))/P$ where $\pi$ is the projection of $A$ to$A/P$ via the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by Im(f)?

Comment: The image of f. If in your example you mean the injection of B into A then it's just B.